# jquery mobile reset page after clicking on link

Tags: jquery-mobile, reset, clear-cache

I have a page called "top up",
    top up /a

page home

When I am done with the page "top up" and I go back to the page "home".
I click on the page "top up" again but I still see the parameters I have filled in earlier

How do I reset the "top up" page to its empty state?

page home

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
 <div data-role="header" ></div>
   <div data-role="content">
       <a href="#topup"></a>
   </div>
  <div data-role="footer" ></div> 
</div>
```

page top up:

```
<div data-role="page" id="topup">
    <div data-role="header" ></div>
    <div data-role="content">
       <input type="text" name="test"/>
    </div>
      <div data-role="footer" ></div> 
</div>
```

details:
jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js
jquery-2.1.0.min.js

Comment: add more details, jQM verion, HTML markup..etc

Comment: What parameter you want to reset?

Comment: I want to reset the whole page "top up"

Comment: `$(document).on("pagecontainerbeforeshow", function () { $("input").val(""); });` to reset input fields.

Comment: Thanks @Omar your solution helped me in the right direction.